# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to display map from google map on file html.twig, but this errors it displayed to me

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

my twig :

```js
let map, google;
let markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initMap() {
  const haightAshbury = {
    lat: 36.77355514795189,
    lng: 9.088027850665279
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: haightAshbury,
    draggable: true

  });
  map.addListener("click", (event) => {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function addMarker(location) {
  deleteMarkers();
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={APIKeyHere}&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async>
</script>

<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

How can i solve it , and thanx

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable called `google` and never assign a value to it:

```
let map,google;
```

Which makes it `undefined`.  You then try to read a value from that `undefined` variable:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Since the library you're importing already has a variable called `google` and you *probably* don't want to shadow that variable, remove it from your variable definition:

```
let map;
```

Comment: still same probleme

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not declare `google` as a variable
2. You are loading the API with a callback function (`initMap`). This means that the `initMap` function will be called once the API has finished loading but you are using `new google.maps.InfoWindow();` outside of your callback function, hence the error

You should move that line to within the callback function, or delete it since you don't seem to be using Infowindows (at least not in the code you provided).

Comment: i removed the init map from api Key then i added window.google in init function and i still have the same problem